# How to write this (Sub query select) Query in Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I Need to know how to write this query in Doctrine 2 (I'm using symfony2 with it)

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT m.id, m.reportName, m.createdAt, m.fileName, v.name 
    FROM Monitoring m 
    JOIN Venture v 
    ON m.venture_name = v.name 
    ORDER BY createdAt DESC
) AS r 
GROUP BY r.reportName, r.name
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
```

My Entities are: "Venture", "Monitory"

Comment: I knew how to do it with Native SQL in Doctrine 2 and add the mapping but in the end the result was too complicated specially for beginners, and we (at work) are not usually allowed to run too complicated code, it should be easily understandable by anyone. so I wonder if there's a way to write such query using the built-in methods in doctrine?